# Flow Copying a Value To a different field - Editable Fields

Tags: visual-workflow, opportunity, custom-field

I am currently building out a flow to copy the value of the Annual Recurring Revenue field (Recurring Revenue is also the name of the field) to populate in the ARR Booking Field automatically. However, I want to still be able to edit the ARR booking field. For example, say the Annual Recurring Revenue field amount is 25,000; it then populates the ARR booking Field for 25,000, but we only had an ARR booking of 18,000. I still want to be able to edit the ARR booking field. In most cases, the values will be the same, but there are still a few instances where they differ. How I have the flow currently set up: if I change the value, it automatically reverts to what is in the Annual Recurring Revenue field; it does not take the new value.

I am new to building out flows so any guidance and advice is helpful! I know the way I have my flow set up is incorrect for the needs I am asking, but I am unsure what to add to it.

**Flow**:
Configure Trigger - A Record Is created or Updated

Set Entry Conditions - None

Fast Field Updates is selected

**Update Records Component**

- Use the opportunity record that triggered the flow.
- No Conditions
- Set Field Values for the Opportunity Record
  Field - ARR booking   Value is pulling from Recurring Revenue Field

TIA!!

[image][image][image]

Comment: You need some criteria that ensures the flow is only run if the ARR value changes and the ARR Booking was the same as the previous ARR value...

Answer (score 1):

On the assumption that the ARR Booking field is on your Opportunity object, you want something like the following Fast Field Updates flow:

1. On create or update of Opportunity:

   1. Entry conditions: "Annual Recurring Revenue" Is Changed "True"
   2. A decision:

      1. Custom Condition Logic Is Met:

         - Condition Logic: 1 AND (2 OR 3)

         1. "ARR Booking" Is Changed "False"
         2. "$Record > Opportunity Id" Is Null "True"
         3. "$Record__Prior > Annual Recurring Revenue" Equals "$Record > ARR Booking"
      2. If the condition requirements are met:

         1. An assignment:

            1. "$Record > ARR Booking" Equals "$Record > Annual Recurring Revenue"

This ensures that the flow updates the ARR Booking, setting it to the ARR value, if the ARR is changing but only when someone didn't manually also change the ARR Booking when updating the ARR, and when the ARR Booking was the same as the ARR before the current update to the ARR, or when the record is first created and the ARR Booking value was not updated.

The flow structure is like:

[image: Copy ARR to ARR Booking when needed]

Comment: Hmm, I created this exact flow and it looks like it is still not working. The amount in the Annual Recurring Revenue field does not even populate to the ARR booking on the opportunity

Comment: Sorry, I realised there is a specific need to handle record creation. In that scenario the ARR Booking needs to be set from ARR if the ARR Booking is null. I will try to update the answer with the details later.

Comment: Answer updated to cater for the record creation